# Rails 3 - Help with a FORM_FOR tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following form_for tag:

```
<%=form_for [:project, @permission], :remote => true do |f| %>


<form method="post" id="edit_permission_52" data-remote="true" class="edit_permission" action="/projects/52/permissions/useronspace" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

The ID looks right = edit_permissions_52

But the action path is all messed up...

It should be
/projects/#PROJECTID#/permissions/useronproject

but instead Rails is making it

```
/projects/#PERMISSIONID#/
```

which is breaking everything.

Does this make sense to you? thanks

Comment: You should just need to hand `form_for` something like `(@project, :remote => true)`, right? (Maybe I'm missing something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific project id, you need to use @project in the array, not :projects.   :projects is for a collection, not a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Is @permission nested on projects? If so, maybe try something like

```
= form_for [@permission.project, @permission]
```

It looks like it's trying to use the @permission id as the project_id. If not, you'd just need to sent it the @permission object (seems likely this is what you want).

```
= form_for @permission, :remote => true
```